# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] different on localhost versus deployment staging server

Tags: php, localhost, staging

We discovered bugs in our site after deploying from our localhost development environment to our staging server.
We narrowed the bugs down to the following PHP code snippet:

```
     $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

We use that to construct paths to various files used by our website.

For example:

```
         // EXAMPLE #1 -- THIS WORKS ON OUR LOCAL MACHINE
      $theSelectedImage = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/ourWebSite/egyptVase.png";

        // EXAMPLE #2 --BUT IT MUST BE THIS TO WORK ON THE STAGING SERVER
      $theSelectedImage = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/egyptVase.png";
```

Here is the crux of the problem:

- on our localhost machine, **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**   resolves to '**localhost**' -- notice we then need to append our website folder name like I show in EXAMPLE #1 above.  I.E. on our localhost machine, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is *unaware* of which website folder involved -- we have to append it.
- but on our staging server, **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**   resolves to '**www.ourWebSite.com**'.
  In that case we don't need to append anything -- the staging web server returns our website folder.

Have we thought of a couple kludgy inelegant 'snide-remarks-in-code-reviews' workarounds.  Yes.

But I'm thinking there's a better way -- any ideas?

Comment: are you using apache as the webserver?  in any case, it seems like if both hosts had the same documentroot, you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Yes, Apache- and PHP vers.5 on both local and staging servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config file is the correct answer.. I use an default and override set up. 
In config.php

```
$config = array('url' => 'http://production.url'); // 'conf1'=> 'var1', etc
$dev_config = array();
@include_once('dev-config.php');
$config = array_merge($config, $dev_config);
```

In dev-config.php you add any overrides to the $dev_config

```
$dev_config['url'] = 'http://localhost/ourWebSite';
```

Then in production, I just delete the dev-config file. Super easy, works flawlessly.

If you want to keep it the way you have it, this can also be solved with an http.conf tweak on your dev box. You need to set your documentRoot to what ever it is now plus the /ourWebSite that way http://localhost/ will point to the same folder with in your code as http://production.url/

Comment: This is slick.  I love the way the dev-config.php gets thrown off the bridge when the training wheels are not needed, nice.  For right now though I'm doing your 2nd suggestion which, while being more admin than coding, is clean and means no differences between dev and production environment -- thanks!

Comment: n/p - I'm pretty sure I picked up the idea from SO somewhere a couple of years ago, so only fitting to share it back :)

Answer (score 4):

One option is to have a configuration file that would pull properly depending on what host it's on (normally based on `APPLICATION_ENV`).  Zend Framework does this by loading the correct section of a `.ini` file corresponding to the `APPLICATION_ENV` in the apache config.  You could use a PHP file with an array or anything else, really.  All you would need to do is set the `APPLICATION_ENV` to be one thing on staging/production but something different on dev servers.

A simple example:

```
switch (APPLICATION_ENV) {
    case 'dev':
        define('APPLICATION_URL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/ourWebSite');
        break;
    case 'production':
    case 'staging':
        define('APPLICATION_URL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        break;
}
```

Comment: We started down that path and had a 'differences'-type of config file but some people started b_tching about using/maintaining it and it was dropped. Good suggestion though.

Comment: that is definitely the way to go, or in a similar manner, have a single config file but add the value like `$config['paths']['dev']['homepath']` and `$config['paths']['staging']['homepath']`, etc and then use `$config['paths'][ APPLICATION_ENV ]['homepath']`

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
function get_homepath(){

   $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   if ( $host == 'localhost' ){ return $host . '/ourWebSite/'; }

   return $host . '/';

}
```

Comment: +1, This would work, thanks.  Was hoping to avoid it though but if there's no more elegant way, man I'm there because it solves the problem. I was hoping there's mindblowingly cool way to tackle it that we aren't aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Usually people set up different environment settings depending on if its a development environment or production environment. The reason for this, as you found out, is to easily move code around from development to production.

Instead of inserting a $_SERVER variable into the url directly, set up a condition that will check $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], find out what environment we are, and inject a different variable holding the real path for your scripts.